# How to parse specific parts of nested JSON format into csv in python (pandas)

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing

I have a nested JSON file which I fail to parse into flatten csv. 
I want to have the following columns in the csv: 
id, name, path, tags (a column for each of them), points (I need x\y values of the 4 dots)

example of the JSON input:

```
{
"name": "test",
"securityToken": "test Token",
"videoSettings": {
    "frameExtractionRate": 15
},
"tags": [
    {
        "name": "Blur Reject",
        "color": "#FF0000"
    },
    {
        "name": "Blur Poor",
        "color": "#800000"
    }
],
"id": "Du1qtrZQ1",
"activeLearningSettings": {
    "autoDetect": false,
    "predictTag": true,
    "modelPathType": "coco"
},
"version": "2.1.0",
"lastVisitedAssetId": "ddee3e694ec299432fed9e42de8741ad",
"assets": {
    "0b8f6f214dc7066b00b50ae16cf25cf6": {
        "asset": {
            "format": "jpg",
            "id": "0b8f6f214dc7066b00b50ae16cf25cf6",
            "name": "1.jpg",
            "path": "c:\temp\1.jpg",
            "size": {
                "width": 1500,
                "height": 1125
            },
            "state": 2,
            "type": 1
        },
        "regions": [
            {
                "id": "VtDyR9Ovl",
                "type": "POLYGON",
                "tags": [
                    "3",
                    "9",
                    "Dark Poor"
                ],
                "boundingBox": {
                    "height": 695.2110389610389,
                    "width": 1111.607142857143,
                    "left": 167.41071428571428,
                    "top": 241.07142857142856
                },
                "points": [
                    {
                        "x": 167.41071428571428,
                        "y": 252.02922077922076
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 208.80681818181816,
                        "y": 891.2337662337662
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 1252.232142857143,
                        "y": 936.2824675324675
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 1279.017857142857,
                        "y": 241.07142857142856
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "version": "2.1.0"
    },
    "0155d8143c8cad85b5b9d392fd2895a4": {
        "asset": {
            "format": "jpg",
            "id": "0155d8143c8cad85b5b9d392fd2895a4",
            "name": "2.jpg",
            "path": "c:\temp\2.jpg",
            "size": {
                "width": 1080,
                "height": 1920
            },
            "state": 2,
            "type": 1
        },
        "regions": [
            {
                "id": "7FFl_diM2",
                "type": "POLYGON",
                "tags": [
                    "Dark Poor"
                ],
                "boundingBox": {
                    "height": 502.85714285714283,
                    "width": 820.3846153846155,
                    "left": 144.08653846153848,
                    "top": 299.2207792207792
                },
                "points": [
                    {
                        "x": 152.39423076923077,
                        "y": 311.68831168831167
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 144.08653846153848,
                        "y": 802.077922077922
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 964.4711538461539,
                        "y": 781.2987012987012
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 935.3942307692308,
                        "y": 299.2207792207792
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "version": "2.1.0"
    }
```

}

I tried using pandas's json_normalize and realized I don't fully understand how to specify the columns I wish to parse:

```
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 


f = open(r'c:\temp\test-export.json') 
data = json.load(f) # load as json
f.close()
df = json_normalize(data) #load json into dataframe
df.to_csv(r'c:\temp\json-to-csv.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

The results are hard to work with because I didn't specify what I want (iteirate trough specific array and append it to the CSV)
This where I wish your help.

I assume i don't fully understand how the normalize works and suspect it is not the best way to deal with this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: you should provide an example output as well based on the data you provided. Also you should show what you already tried and why it didn't work. We are here to help you if you struggle but not to solve the problem for you. Show some effort in solving it yourself. See [tour] and [ask] for more information how to ask a good question.

Comment: Yes I get that. I will edit the question and provide more info

Comment: @AlexanderPushkarev why should he want to represent nested JSON in a CSV when he only need parts of the JSON file in CSV which is not nested in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. Since you didn't provide an example output I did something on my own.

```
import json
import csv

f = open(r'file.txt')
data = json.load(f)
f.close()
with open("output.csv", mode="w", newline='') as out:
    w = csv.writer(out)
    header = ["id","name","path","tags","points"]
    w.writerow(header)
    for asset in data["assets"]:
        data_point = data["assets"][asset]
        output = [data_point["asset"]["id"]]
        output.append(data_point["asset"]["name"])
        output.append(data_point["asset"]["path"])
        output.append(data_point["regions"][0]["tags"])
        output.append(data_point["regions"][0]["points"])
        w.writerow(output)
```

## Output

```
id,name,path,tags,points
0b8f6f214dc7066b00b50ae16cf25cf6,1.jpg,c:\temp\1.jpg,"['3', '9', 'Dark Poor']","[{'x': 167.41071428571428, 'y': 252.02922077922076}, {'x': 208.80681818181816, 'y': 891.2337662337662}, {'x': 1252.232142857143, 'y': 936.2824675324675}, {'x': 1279.017857142857, 'y': 241.07142857142856}]"
0155d8143c8cad85b5b9d392fd2895a4,2.jpg,c:\temp\2.jpg,['Dark Poor'],"[{'x': 152.39423076923077, 'y': 311.68831168831167}, {'x': 144.08653846153848, 'y': 802.077922077922}, {'x': 964.4711538461539, 'y': 781.2987012987012}, {'x': 935.3942307692308, 'y': 299.2207792207792}]"
```

Comment: This is very helpful! I understand now that I look for a very far solution (normalizing and flattening) while your solution is much neater.

Comment: @jonny3000 you're welcome. Be aware that regions is an array and in your example it only has one element that's why I put `[0]` there. But in case there are more element you have to address that problem properly. But I thought since you talked about 4 points it is maybe always only in the size of 1? Yeah flattening and normalizing is probably not the right way to go for this.